# Which graphical display method should i use for representing 36'000 Events? X/Y Coordinate? Plotter? Something else?

Tags: java, plot, javafx, javafx-8, coordinate-systems

I have following problem:

I dont know how to display so much data in a graphical way.
I could use a x/y coordinate system and draw pixels on it. So when i have the resolution 10Hz ( 36000 possible events ) i have to draw 36000 pixel on that graph.

Is there kind of a better solution for my problem? Do you have any hints for me how i should do this? How to draw so many pixels on a graph?

The resolution should also be changeable to

10Hz     --> 36000 Events in a hour. In one second maximum 10 events. 13:00:00:1, 13:00:00:2, ......
100Hz   --> 3600   Events in a hour. In one second maximum 1 event. 13:00:01, 13:00:02, 13:00:03 ....
1000Hz --> 360     Events in a hour. In one minute maximum 1 event. 13:01:00, 13:02:00, 13:03:00 .....

It should look like that...
 
https://gyazo.com/f397f33a2a3afd7833b881e1322b86ef

EDIT: I'm going to use scrolling and zooming.
Thanks for every little help!

Comment: The first step is to decide how to show the events *meaningfully* - zooming? scrolling? aggregating? layers? But that is a business/design question, not a technical one.